# How can I create this type of pattern material or texture with nodes?

Tags: texturing, materials

How can I create this type of pattern material or texture with nodes?

[image]

Comment: Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a similar material with this node tree. You can probably manage to get similar results by using a voronoi texture instead of all the math operations at the begining

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Alex, I do like your texture result, but I couldn't understand all the Nodes. I followed your advice using Voronoi, and got a little bit similar result. Here's what I did, but I'm sure it can be improved if you like to elaborate on it. https://ibb.co/zS2rhtx

Comment: @blenderbreath I added a blender file to the answer if that helps. I made it with blender 4.0 so if there is any issue you know why.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a hole and bake its normals:

[image]

Then use the normal map as a pattern:

[image]